# Setting the color of the \fancyfoot in certain pages

Tags: header-footer

I use the following command for the footnotes, at the preamble:

```
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\color{purple}"Random Text"}
```

Is there a way to change the color only for certain pages (for example: all the pages between 20 and 50)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{%
\ifnum\value{page}>19
\ifnum\value{page}<51
\color{purple}%
\fi
\fi
"Random Text"}
```

---

A full example

```
\documentclass[twoside,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,color,lipsum}

\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{%
\ifnum\value{page}>19
\ifnum\value{page}<51
\color{red}%
\fi
\fi
"Random Text \thepage"}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. It changes all the pages. I want (e.g.) purple color for pages 1-19, 51-100 and blue for 20-50.

Comment: @GSpyros that just does purple on pages 20-50, which is what you asked for in the question

Comment: @GSpyros I added a complete test document above